# Make it easier to report a bug or feature request from "about this app" dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Can we make it easier to report bugs and feature requests from the about section in the app?

In particular this part could help:

> Bugs or feature requests should be reported on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and tagged **ios-app**.

Maybe we can make a link of *Bugs* and *feature requests*, which automatically opens a new question in the app with the appropriate tags and possibly the version number.

This would make it a lot easier to make feature requests and report bugs and diagnose them.

Comment: +1 I agree with you. I have seen many app bug reports / requests posted without the mention of version number and proper tags. In most of the cases we ask this info in comments but if OP posts the question and leaves for few hours then we have no way to diagnose them. Your feature-request will sure take care of this issue.

Comment: +1... eh, it's not [tag:android-app]..? perhaps I need to create (or find existing) request too...

Comment: I don't think there is. Go create one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be in the next build.

The new *About this app* dialog:

> [image: Help screen showing new options]

When clicking *Submit a bug report*:

> [image: Generated bug report]

Comment: This is one of the most user-friendly of all the great improvements you've made! Thanks for the feature request Patrick!