# Can we make the device version reported more meaningful?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, bug-reports

Since a [recent feature request was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264447/245360), the iOS app adds the version number to the bug report when reporting from the app itself.

Sample:

> - App Version: 1.3.2.229
> - Device: iPhone7,2
> - OS Version: Version 8.4.1 (Build 12H321)

The device version shown is the hardware version string, and not something human beings find easy to understand.

Can we convert that string into something meaningful, so instead of the version string "iPhone7 ,2" just "iPhone 6"?

Comment: oh, so it's a code name... go figure! :)

Comment: I can (though it will always be incomplete in Septembers) with a lookup table.  I didn't bother because it's more than likely that I won't need to know its an iPhone 6 and if I do I can look it up. I guess I'm not the only person who reads reports though.

Comment: Yes. Usually I try to reproduce issues (else I feel silly upvoting). The version number is quite useful when reproducing an issue since it is sometimes device related. @Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  Though your iPhone 7 will show up as something like: `Device: Unknown (iPhone9,1)`.